# How to apply a function along an axis in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I have a matrix with shape:

`x = np.random.rand(3, 10, 2, 6)`

As you can see, there are only two arrays along an `axis=2`.

I have a function that accepts these two arrays:

```
def f(arr1, arr2): # arr1 with shape (6, ) and arr2 with (6, )
    return np.sum(arr1, arr2) # for simplicity
```

How can I apply this function along the second axis to `x` array in a vectorized way? Such that resulting array will be of shape `[3, 10, dim of output]`.

I came across [apply_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) routine, but it requires that `f` accepts only 1D slice.

Comment: Does `f` expect a pair of 2 or 3d arrays?  `f(x[:,:,0], x[:,:,1]`?   To be clear, write a fully iterative solution, iterating on the first 2 dimensions (or more as needed).  By the way, `apply_along_axis`, even when it works, is just a convenience tool; it does not improve performance.

Comment: @hpaulj `f` expects to accept a pair of 1D arrays.

Comment: A pair - both from `x`?  or from `x` and another like sized array?  `f( x[i,j,0], x[i,j,1])`?  or `f( x[i,j,k]. y[i,j,k])`?  No that it really matters.  I think you need the same kind of iteration.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, exactly,  `f(x[i,j,0], x[i,j,1])`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it entirely arbitrarily, but your particular case reduces to

```
x.sum(axis=2)
```

If you want to add the arrays as in your code:

```
x[:, :, 0, :] + x[:, :, 1, :]
```

Comment: my function is not `sum`, it is just for simplicity

Comment: That's why I said you can't always do it for arbitrary functions. Show what you actually want and I may be able to help.

Comment: @MadPhysicist is correct.  It's hard to know how to help you with knowing the function.  In general, if the function is a numpy ufunc, then `np.foo.reduce` might be what you're looking for, where `foo` is whatever the normal function's name is.